# how can i solve this duration problem in audio player package?

Tags: flutter, dart, package

i use [audioplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers#-installing-tab-) package for audio.

but problem is with duration.
some file this package can collect duration without getting problem .
but some are even in same server this is can't collect duration.

check this audio file this is error for duration

https://www.jollygul.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Kalaam-e-Mawla-%E2%80%93-Various-Themes.mp3

but in same server this is ok :o

https://www.jollygul.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Kalaam-e-Mawla-Patience-Gratitude.mp3

what can i do ?

**Note :** Here is no problem with audio

Comment: Its because of the url encoding. There seems to be this character `–` in the url. Replace all encoded characters with url safe characters

Comment: this is work 
https://www.jollygul.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Kalaam-e-Mawla-Patience-Gratitude.mp3

but again this is problem every time
https://www.jollygul.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Kalaam-e-Mawla-Servanthood-And-Purity.mp3


so i need to change the url?

Comment: and here is no problem with audio.
Just problem with duration